# BT hub5 / BT broadband Infinity 2 and TP-Link Archer D2

Tags: adsl, vdsl, bt-infinity

I have BT Infinity 2 with a BT HUB 5 router which is connected to an Openreach Socket on the wall via an ADSL cable. On the router it says ADSL plug as well. As I am having some problems with online gaming, I bought a TP-Link Archer D2 phone line AC750 ADSL2+ modem router.

When going through the Quick Connection Setup steps from the TP-Link's IP address,it won't connect to the Internet. First of all the auto connect wizard cannot detect the connection type, the ADSL LED keeps bleeping, vanishing and reappearing. I am directed to "*No, configure myself*".

Some people say BT Infinity 2 is VDSL while some say it's ADSL and are not compatible. What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: What do BT say? What problems, precisely, are you experiencing,  whilst gaming, that direct you to the problem being your modem/router (bearing in mind BT are one of the leading UK broadband suppliers and their equipment is pretty good)...

Comment: BT routers always used to be keyed specifically to the line & account. You could never swap to your own router. idk whether the newer Infinity structure has changed that, but I do know that for Virgin even if you swap to a new 'identical' router, you need to ring them to get it switched on.

Answer (score 0):

BT infinity is VDSL and would not work with this router without a fibre modem as well. (E.g open reach box).

Comment: @DragonLord It looks like an answer to me: the question expresses confusion about whether the service is ADSL or VDSL and James asserts the answer to that. It would be better if this was backed up by, say, a link to the relevant documentation on BT's website.